# How create alias for a path in bash .profile?

Tags: alias, .profile

Under macOS, in `.profile` I want to create an alias `myproj` for a path, say `~/Documents/mywork/project`, so that in Terminal I can use the command:

```
open myproj
```

I tried simply adding to `.profile` the line...

```
alias myproj="~/Documents/mywork/project"
```

... but after restarting Terminal, when I then try `open myproj` I get error: `The file /Users/me/myproj does not exist.`

What's wrong?

Comment: Also, if you are using `bash`, you'll want it in `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Why `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.profile` ? Note that my default shell for Terminal.app under macOS is `zsh`, and somehow my `~/.profile` also gets read (even though I find no explicit loading of it in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: "if you are using `bash`..." - it depends on your shell.

Answer (score 2):

`alias` [doesn't work that way](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/).

Try

alias myproj="open ~/Documents/mywork/project"

You type

```
myproj # NOT "open myproj"
```

the parser processes the alias and changes it to

```
open ~/Documents/mywork/project
```

## Addendum

Maybe an alias isn't really what you wanted anyway.

You could do it more like your original attempt with a variable.
Instead of

```
alias myproj="~/Documents/mywork/project"
```

try just

```
myproj="~/Documents/mywork/project"
```

Then to open it,

```
open $myproj # breaks if there are embedded spaces...
```

or, better,

```
open "$myproj"
```

If you want more functionality, consider a [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) instead, though for this it's probably not needed.